# How head node's nextRef got updated while updating tail node's nextRef in Single Linked List

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to understand LinkedList implementation based on the reference link http://www.java2novice.com/data-structures-in-java/linked-list/singly-linked-list/.

There they have created a Node class as below:

```
class Node<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    private T value;
    private Node<T> nextRef;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Node<T> getNextRef() {
        return nextRef;
    }
    public void setNextRef(Node<T> ref) {
        this.nextRef = ref;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(T arg) {
        if(arg == this.value){
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And implemented Singly Linked List as below:

```
    public class SinglyLinkedListImpl<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    public void add(T element){

        Node<T> nd = new Node<T>();
        nd.setValue(element);
        System.out.println("Adding: "+element);
        /**
         * check if the list is empty
         */
        if(head == null){
            //since there is only one element, both head and 
            //tail points to the same object.
            head = nd;
            tail = nd;
        } else {
            //set current tail next link to new node
            //When this line gets executed, it's also updating head variable's nextRef object. How that works?!?!
            tail.setNextRef(nd);
            //set tail as newly created node
            tail = nd;
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'm unable to understand when below line gets executed, it's also updating head variable's nextRef object. How that works?!?!

> tail.setNextRef(nd);

I have tried debugging and see the objects' values and noticed that in head variable only they're keep adding the given elements with `nextRef`. But how that `head.nextRef` get's updated at `tail.setNextRef(nd)` step!!!

Might be a silly question, but gone crazy with it like how this happens! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When first element is added, head and tail both point to that same element. When second element is added, tail.setNextRef(nd) will be equal to head.setNextRef(nd) because tail and head has same reference. After that, tail=nd, which means tail is now pointing to the current node, and from that point onwards, current node's next will be set through tail.setNextRef(nd) and immediately after that, tail's will have new current node's reference.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. But while running `tail.setNextRef(nd)` step, nextRef value of head variable also getting updated with current node through out. For example, if we try with multiple values 1, 5, 7... all the time, whenever this line executes, nextRef of both head & tail getting updated with value & null. That's my doubt like how it updates both head & tail nextRef variable.

Comment: Yep, got it. Same reference will be there in both head & tail. So whenever we try to set next node value, it updates both the places.